# Making raw_input capitalize specific letters to match dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am developing a text-based RPG.  Right now, I am creating a combat mechanic that provides the player with their options of attack, and executing code based off the items a player has in their inventory dictionary, like so (I will keep the code simple for obvious reasons):

```
inventory = {'Weapons': ['Iron Longsword', 'Dagger'],
            'Gold': 10,
            'Spells': [' ']}

print "Your attack methods are: [Melee] -- %s, [Spells] -- %s" % (inventory["Weapons"], inventory["Spells"]

attack = raw_input("Choose an attack method provided above: ")
if attack == inventory["Weapons"] or attack == inventory["Spells"]:
     #Initiate combat...
```

I could be understanding this concept incorrectly, but the problem I am facing is when an item is added to the inventory, it is shown in proper capitalization, e.g. "Iron Longsword" vs. "iron longsword".  I think the issue is that when the if statement goes to check the dictionary for the items the player typed in under the raw_input 'attack', it doesn't recognize the item unless it is capitalized correctly.  However, I want to allow the player to just type in the weapon or spell regardless of pre-existing capitalization.

I figured there may be one real solutions to the problem, again I could definitely be wrong about this.  The solution being to edit the raw input to translate to proper caps, just like I do when the characters should be all lower case with '.lower()'

I appreciate any help with simple problems like this.  Thanks again stack overflow for being so fantastic to me while I try to learn programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since i have used python but the below code segment should test if the input is equal to one of the attacks or spells no matter what the capitalization is. You can either make both string capitalized or lower case when you test them. I would suggest doing this any time your testing a string in the future so your users doesn't need to type his input Case sensitively.

```
if attack.lower() == inventory["Weapons"].lower() or attack == inventory["Spells"].lower():
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compare two strings like

```
str1 = 'Longsword'
str2 = 'LongSword'

print str1.lower() == str1.lower()
```

evaluates True.

So you can use the lower() method and have non-capitalized keys and values.

You should also use

```
if attack in [x.lower() for x in inventory["Weapons"]]
```

instead of comparing a string to a list like you do now.